# onChange handler in async typeahead is not called when triggered using "user event" in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, typeahead.js, testing-library, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to test a specific functionality that's defined inside onChange handler of AsyncTypeahead component from react-bootstrap-typeahead library. But onChange handler and selected property are not triggered at all. They are triggered when I type something on UI and select one option from typeahead dropdown. But from tests, both onChange and selected are not triggered. Here's the code for your reference:

Search.jsx

```
const getSelectedObject = value => {
        if (value) {
            return {name: value};
        }
        return value;
    };
const Search = props => {
    const client = useApolloClient();
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const onSearch = async searchInput => {
        props.clear();
        if (!searchInput) return;
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const variables = {
                fields: props.fields,
                value: searchInput,
            };
            const res = await client.query({
                query: props.query,
                variables,
            });
            const newOptions = res ? res.data: [];
            setOptions(newOptions);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const searchValue = debounce(onSearch, 2000);
    return (
        <th style={props.style || {minWidth: "100px"}} id={props.id}>
            <label style={{visibility: "hidden"}} htmlFor={`${props.id}_input`}>
                {props.id}
            </label>
            <AsyncTypeahead
                inputProps={{name: props.name, id: `${props.id}_input`}}
                labelKey="name"
                id="fields"
                placeholder={props.placeholder || "Search"}
                onChange={(value) => console.log("onchange trigger", value)}
                selected={(val) => getSelectedObject(val)}
                isLoading={isLoading}
                onSearch={searchValue}
                options={options}
            />
        </th>
    );
};

Search.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selected: PropTypes.object,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    accountRole: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    fieldNames: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

Search.defaultProps = {
    selected: undefined,
    placeholder: "Search",
};

export default Search;
```

Search.test.jsx

```
test.only("selecting an option from search result SHOULD call ONCHANGE handler", async () => {
                render(<ConversationSearch {...props} />);

        // When
        userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("combobox"), "to");

        // Then
        expect(screen.getByRole("combobox").getAttribute("value")).toBe("to");
        await waitFor(() =>
            expect(screen.getByRole("listbox")).toBeInTheDocument(),
        );
        expect(
            screen.getByRole("link", {name: "Type to search..."}),
        ).toBeDefined();
        await waitFor(() =>
            expect(
                screen.getByRole("link", {name: "Searching..."}),
            ).toBeInTheDocument(),
        );
        await waitFor(() =>
            expect(
                screen.getByRole("option", {name: "option1"}),
            ).toBeInTheDocument(),
        );
        expect(
            screen.getByRole("option", {name: "option2"}),
        ).toBeInTheDocument();

        expect(screen.getByLabelText("option1")).toBeVisible();

                fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole("combobox"), {target: {value: "option1"}});

       // expect(screen.getByRole("combobox").getAttribute("value")).toBe("option1");
    });
```

I have modified the parts of the code to keep the focus more on component rather than business context.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what functionality you're trying to test, but it sounds like you just want to assert that `onChange` is called when an option is selected. Note that the library [already tests this](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/main/src/components/AsyncTypeahead/AsyncTypeahead.test.tsx#L116), but if you insist on confirming that, go ahead.

Based on the code in `Search.jsx`, it doesn't look like `onChange` is being passed on to the typeahead, so be sure to do that. Something like this should work (I haven't actually tested):

```
test.only("selecting an option from search result SHOULD call ONCHANGE handler", async () => {
  // Pass a spy to the `onChange` handler.
  const onChange = jest.fn();
  render(<ConversationSearch {...props} onChange={onChange} />);

  userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("combobox"), "to");

  ...

  const option = await screen.findByRole("option", { name: "option1" });

  userEvent.click(option);

  // `onChange` should be called after a selection.
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```